# urxvt- play mp3 instead of beep

Tags: x11, audio, rxvt

Does anyone know how to make urxvt play a mp3 file in replacement of a system beep? My PC does not have a pc speaker so I need a way to make terminal notifications go through sound card.

Comment: Under which Unix variant? If Linux, which distribution? I don't think that rxvt has anything like that, but most unix variants let you direct all system beeps to a sound card (in fact, most do so by default).